# How to check whether a specific element exists in a list of dataframes in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, element, exists

Suppose I have the following list of dataframes:

```
A = list(fruits = data.frame(V1 = c("Apple", "Banana", "Orange")), vegetables = data.frame(V1 = c("cucumber", "lettuce")))
```

I would like to know that lettuce exists in the "vegetables" dataframe in the list but not in the fruits (could be a TRUE or FALSE or 0 or 1 output)

I tried the following function:

```
map_lgl(A, `%in%`, x = "lettuce") %>% as.integer()
```

But I am getting an output of 0 0. I also need the output to also indicate that "vegetables" is the dataframe in the list of which "lettuce" is found in

It seems that I need to access the elements of the list somehow but I don't know how.

I am sorry I'm new in R. Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `sapply` :

```
sapply(A, function(x) 'lettuce' %in% x$V1)

#    fruits vegetables 
#     FALSE       TRUE
```

To get the names :

```
names(A)[sapply(A, function(x) 'lettuce' %in% x$V1)]
#[1] "vegetables"
```

---

With `purrr` functions.

```
library(purrr)
map_lgl(A, ~'lettuce' %in% .x$V1)
#    fruits vegetables 
#     FALSE       TRUE 
map_int(A, ~'lettuce' %in% .x$V1)
#    fruits vegetables 
#         0          1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply`

```
unlist(lapply(A, function(x) 'lettuce' %in% x$V1))
#fruits vegetables 
# FALSE       TRUE
```